# Transaction like logic while using web services

Tags: java, soap, transactions

There are several update staments that can be done by web service calls. Those staments should be transactional; they must be done if and only if all can be done.

I cannot change the web services. what I can do is try to change all of them, if one of them fails I change back the previous ones. This plain sloution is pretty ugly.

Is there a more elegant approach to this problem ?

note: I am using JavaEE, SOAP, Spring MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have a **@TransactionAttribute** for different targets(method and class).
If you apply this annotation to a class with appropriate ***TransactionAttributeType***(Constants) then that transaction strategy will apply to all the methods inside that class i.e You can keep all calls to your update statements in this class and inject this class where you are having your web services, so if even one update call fails it will rollback

Comment: Please don't hesitate to mark the question as answered, if the above has helped  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a Transactional class which uses Apache HTTP utils to call these web services one by one. ( This class should have a @Transactional annotation)